# How to get the CMIS field value

Tags: entities, theming, nodes

I have configured the cmis and the cmis views modules to Drupal. I can access to my distant Alfresco repository when I test the different fields available.
My goal is to propose to my customer two way for inserting an image :
- basic upload
- from their alfresco server

I had various content types. So I created an image field and a CMIS Field.
If the user has his image in the Alfresco server, he will use the associate field (CMIS Field) and when he has it on his desktop he will use the basic upload field.

What is the way of getting the CMIS Field value in my template ?

**EDIT 1 :**
I tried to print_r the variable $row (The raw SQL result that can be used) and I found my field :

```
[field_test_alfresco] => Array
(
    [und] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [path] => workspace://SpacesStore/bd8ck22c-452b-4d79-9616-2c163584036b
                    [title] => 1372936869055_content.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

I don't see how to use these data.

**EDIT 2**:

Thanks to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608695/drupal-cmis-alfresco-link-issue?rq=1) It seems that the module uses the method `CMISService->getLink()`, with the kind of path I displayed before, when you update or add contents to alfresco via drupal.

Maybe if we can create a CMISService object from my template...

Comment: Could you post the code you've already tried, along with the errors/problems you're currently experiencing?

Comment: Hi, see my edit. I'm looking for some methodology first of all